# how to split in java this String "REMOTE:1|" to "REMOTE"

Tags: java, list, split

I need to split this String

> "REMOTE:1|"

to

> "REMOTE"

in java, i have these values in an array. 
I tried

```
String[] splitSpeak = speakValue.split("(\\|");
```

but i dont know how to do it with the other characters

Thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: Have you read the documentation for String?

Comment: Why not `split(":")[0]`?

Comment: or `.replace("(?s):.*", "")`

Comment: @david post your last comment as an answer, please! :) ps you can probably omit `(?s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String[] splitSpeak = speakValue.split(":");`

Answer (score 1):

The `(?s)` makes it work for `"REMOTE:1|\nLOCAL:2|"`

```
"REMOTE:1|".replace("(?s):.*", "")
```